# postgis ST_DWithin with an point and many polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a polygon marked as infested by insects. Would you like to get all the polygons that are within 300 meters from the center of this infested polygon.

My query is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT br.id
FROM insect_focus
JOIN polygons p on insect_focus.polygons_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN polygons pa ON ST_DWithin(pa.coordinate::geography, ST_Centroid(p.coordinate)::geography, 300, true)
WHERE insect_focus.id = 277
```

And the result was: http://prntscr.com/5qk3h2

See the points that postgis returned. And see the area that the map system understood to be 300 meters. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong to me from the picture. What do you think is wrong about the picture?

Comment: Polygons with point in map are generated by Postgis. All polygons with a marker outside of the circle are more than 300 meters from the center focus point.

Comment: My rule is: I want to know all the polygons that have any part of its area up to 300 meters from the focus point.

Comment: ST_Centroid doesn't support geography. Maybe that's part of the problem? [http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html](http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html)

Comment: ST_DWithin generates an ellipsoid rather than an ellipse. See the picture (http://prntscr.com/5qmftj) . It has to do with the SRID, no? How do I get to generate a circle ? I'm using SRID 4326. Sorry ignorance!

Comment: I was saving lat / lon instead of lon / lat. The Google Maps showing the correct region, but reversed projection. When I migrated to mapbox i saw the error . I used the ST_FlipCoordinates and all resolved.